# SWIG with C++ templates: undefined symbol

Tags: c++, python, swig

C++ Templates and SWIG aren't playing nicely together for me.

When I try to import my module I get the error

```
ImportError: ./_simple.so: undefined symbol: _Z9double_itIiET_S0_
```

I am using SWIG 1.3.

Here is a simple example showing the problem:

```
//file: simple.h
template <typename T>
T double_it (T a);

//file: simple.cc
template <typename T>
T double_it (T a) {
  return (2 * a);
}

//file: simple.i
%module "simple"

%{
  #include "simple.h"
%}

%include "simple.h"

%template(int_double_it) double_it <int>;
%template(float_double_it) double_it <float>;

#file: setup.py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
simple_module = Extension('_simple',
                          sources=['simple.i', 'simple.cc'],
                          swig_opts=['-c++'],
                          )
setup (name = 'simple',
       ext_modules = [simple_module],
       py_modules = ["simple"],
       )
```

Then build in with:

```
python setup.py build
```

If I include the contents of simple.cc into simple.i and remove the reference to simple.cc from the setup.py then everything works fine, but that isn't really a solution when things get more complex.

Next I'll give a counter example of something that is similar but doesn't use templates and works fine.

```
//file: simple.h
int double_it (int a);

//file: simple.cc
int double_it (int a) {
  return (2 * a);
}

//file: simple.i
//Same as before but with %template statements removed.
%module "simple"

%{
  #include "simple.h"
%}

%include "simple.h"

#file: setup.py
#Identical to previous example.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically templates are defined in a header file instead of in a cc file. With the setup you have, the compiler cannot find / compile the implementation of the template.

You will need to change the organization of the code so that the template implementation is available:

```
//file: simple.hh
template <typename T>
T double_it (T a) {
  return (2 * a);
}

//file: simple.i
%module "simple"

%{
  #include "simple.hh"
%}

%include "simple.hh" // include it directly into here

%template(int_double_it) double_it <int>;
%template(float_double_it) double_it <float>;

#file: setup.py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
simple_module = Extension('_simple',
                          sources=['simple.i', 'simple.hh'],
                          swig_opts=['-c++'],
                         )
setup (name = 'simple',
       ext_modules = [simple_module],
       py_modules = ["simple"],
       )
```

I appreciate that your example is simplified, but it illustrates the point. You do not have to `%include` the implementation directly (but you do need to `#include` it), but you do have to provide *some* implementation to the SWIG compiler, even if it is a simplified version.

The above should get you going.

Comment: I left the header file out to make things a bit shorter.  Probably I should have left this in to make it look more normal. If you replace the two places where I have "template <typename T> T double_it (T a);" with include header statements you'll get something similar to yours. The main difference is that you are now including the implementation of double_it in the interface file so no linking is required.  I can also get it to work if I do that, but I am having trouble if the implementation is in a separate .cc file.

Comment: I added in a header file into my example so it look more normal.

Comment: You really have to put the implementation in the header file for the compiler to be able to find it and generate the version you need. The only alternative is to explicitly instantiate the template in your .cc file to make sure the instantiation you need exists (to make sure the compiler generates the version you need and it is available at link time). 

"template class double_it<int>;
template class double_it<float>;" What you are running into is really a general question about C++ and template instantiation and less about SWIG specifically